# Salesforce PHP SOAP API get custom object

Tags: php, api, soap, salesforce

I manage to query for the standard SF objects with this code:

```
$contactQuery = "SELECT Id, Name FROM Account";

$contactResponse = $sforceClient->query($contactQuery);

$queryResult = new QueryResult($contactResponse);

foreach ($queryResult->records as $record) {
print_r ($record);
}
```

The problem is that when I try to query for a custom object (products) - I don't get any results.
I tried listing the fields to make sure I query the right fields but didn't manage to do that.

I made sure to add __c after the field names, but unfortunately still no results.
I think my problem is that I might be querying the wrong field names, or not the real object names, is there anywhere special to verify those?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it, 
There is the describeSObjects() method which returns all the objects as  describeSObject() which have all the required data to query any element.
Cheers